# Sonar and Maven artifact deployment

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I'm trying to come up with a pattern of continuous integration in which our Maven project will only deploy artifacts if certain quality thresholds have been met.  We're using Sonar to run the quality reports, but it seems that I have to run:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar && \
mvn deploy -DskipTests -DskipITs
```

(or rather its equivalent as separate Jenkins build steps).

This involves building the code twice, therefore making each overall build job too long for continuous integration.

If I run a one-liner like:

```
mvn clean deploy sonar:sonar
```

the artifacts are deployed to the repository before Sonar is run.  Without moving away from Maven, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the method I used eventually is three separate build steps, as follows:

- mvn clean install -DskipTests -DskipITs
- mvn sonar:sonar
- mvn jar:jar deploy:deploy

This seems to work ok for a Maven multi-module project.  If Sonar fails the build (via the BuildBreaker plugin), then the artifacts are not deployed.  If Sonar passes, then Maven re-attaches the Jars to the project and deploys them.

Answer (score 0):

The Sonar [Maven documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven) suggests running Maven as follows

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
mvn sonar:sonar
```

The "Alternative method" section describes how these goals could be executed as a single step, but then the tests will be run twice.

I don't think there is much you can do to avoid create 2-3 Maven build steps, however, it is possible to configure the [build breaker plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin) to automatically fail your build when your specified quality criteria is breached.

Answer (score 0):

We solve this with a custom Jenkins plugin which invokes Maven 6-10 times. It really isn't that bad, you just have to ensure that all executions which "do stuff" after the `test` phase include `skipTests=true`. The problem can be solved just as well with three Maven build steps:

- `mvn clean package` (I don't like the idea of artifacts being placed in the local repo if they fail Sonar quality gates)
- `mvn sonar:sonar`
- `mvn install (or deploy) -DskipTests=true`

When you say that "building" the project multiple times takes too long, what do you mean, exactly? Maven will not re-compile code which is already up-to-date and you're skipping tests. The remaining processing is not significant enough to become a burden. If you've got some funky plugin running again (in the final invocation), chances are it has a `skip*` option.

You'll find that SonarQube is not just good for checking your code quality, but it is also a great way to enforce build governance. That's not very useful on a small team but it's your only hope of maintaining software quality when you've got dozens or hundreds of developers touching a large codebase, each of whom may or may not be a quality-conscious programmer :). And, of course as Mark said, you'll need to install and enable the Build Breaker plugin.

Comment: I think you have to run the install phase before running Sonar, don't you? This is what the official documentation states.  The problem with running deploy afterwards is that it runs *all* phases again, not just compile.  We have modules that generate code from wsdls, for example, and this takes a non-zero amount of timethat's enough not to want to repeat it.  I've posted my eventual solution above, which avoids this.

Comment: Yep, it's not clean any way you put it. We run the whole lifecycle again the second time around but we throw in all kinds of "-Dskip*" properties.